# how to clearInterval and dynamically change the time in setInterval based on the current activity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript. I need your help to solve this problem.

I have some data that I want to `sliding`. In every data there is 2 side, left side and right side.

The left side contain some images to slide and the right side have one article that if the article height is taller than the frame, it should be moving up, so we can see all the article.

After all the images has been done `sliding/display` and the article is fully readable, it will moving to another data.

I am using javascript command `setInterval` to change the content in *every 5 second*, when 5 second reached, the image is sliding, the next 5 second reached, the next image is sliding again and again until reach the last image.

**The problem is** when the last image is reached but the article is not all displayed yet.

Any idea of this case? How about using `clearInterval` or `setInterval` but the time is dynamically change.

**My Code:**

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var slideContentIndex = 1;
var slideDataIndex = 1;

var slide = $(".slide");
var slideData = $(".slide-data");
var slideContent = slide.find(".slide-content");

function sliding() {
  var slideLength = slide.length;
  var currentSlide = slide.parent().find(".slide.active");
  var slideDataLength = currentSlide.find(".slide-data").length;
  var currentSlideData = currentSlide.find(".slide-data.active");
  var slideContentLength = currentSlideData.find(".slide-content").length;
  var currentContentSlide = currentSlideData.find(".slide-content.active");

  if (slideContentIndex < slideContentLength) {
    currentContentSlide.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
    slideContentIndex += 1;
  } else {
    if (slideDataIndex < slideDataLength) {
      currentSlideData.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active").find(".slide-content").first().addClass("active");
      slideDataIndex += 1;
    } else {
      if (slideIndex < slideLength) {
        currentSlide.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active").find(".slide-data").first().addClass("active").find(".slide-content").first().addClass("active");
        slideIndex += 1;
      } else {
        currentSlide.removeClass("active");
        slide.first().addClass("active").find(".slide-data").first().addClass("active").find(".slide-content").first().addClass("active");
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      currentSlideData.removeClass("active");
      currentSlide.find(".slide-data").first().addClass("active");
      slideDataIndex = 1;
    }
    currentContentSlide.removeClass("active");
    slideContentIndex = 1;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(sliding, 5000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide active">
  <h1>Enjiniring</h1>
  <div class="slide-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <figure class="slide-content active">
        <img src="1478191814Picture5.png" style="max-width: 100%">
        <figcaption class="caption">some caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide-content">
        <img src="ip.png" style="max-width: 100%">
        <figcaption class="caption">some another caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide-content">
        <img src="great.jpg" style="max-width: 100%">
        <figcaption class="caption">some another caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="slide-frame">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce suscipit justo mi, at euismod tortor interdum vel. Duis tincidunt fermentum elementum. Etiam a lectus odio. Sed mollis sapien imperdiet, rutrum massa ut, porta purus. Nulla tincidunt
          elit ut lectus sagittis, ac porta lacus accumsan. Aliquam iaculis ipsum nec orci vestibulum, vitae tincidunt elit ullamcorper. Integer nibh nunc, euismod a metus nec, placerat consectetur mi. Vestibulum et nisi nibh. Phasellus sit amet molestie
          nisi, non sodales tellus. Vestibulum hendrerit lacus sem, eget eleifend sapien lacinia sit amet. Nam condimentum ligula eu nibh luctus tempor. Morbi convallis, eros ac congue laoreet, est erat gravida magna, non lobortis nibh turpis id justo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <figure class="slide-content active">
        <img src="hello.png" style="max-width: 100%">
        <figcaption class="caption">logo indonesia power 2</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="slide-content">
        <img src="/app-visual/assets/upload_files/ip.jpg" style="max-width: 100%">
        <figcaption class="caption">logo indonesia power 3</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="slide-frame">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce suscipit justo mi, at euismod tortor interdum vel. Duis tincidunt fermentum elementum. Etiam a lectus odio. Sed mollis sapien imperdiet, rutrum massa ut, porta purus. Nulla tincidunt
          elit ut lectus sagittis, ac porta lacus accumsan. Aliquam iaculis ipsum nec orci vestibulum, vitae tincidunt elit ullamcorper. Integer nibh nunc, euismod a metus nec, placerat consectetur mi. Vestibulum et nisi nibh. Phasellus sit amet molestie
          nisi, non sodales tellus. Vestibulum hendrerit lacus sem, eget eleifend sapien lacinia sit amet. Nam condimentum ligula eu nibh luctus tempor. Morbi convallis, eros ac congue laoreet, est erat gravida magna, non lobortis nibh turpis id justo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="slide-data"></div>
  <div class="slide-data"></div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: A simple approach I use is define an array of timings e.g.  [5, 5, 5, 10] corresponding to each slides. Now, instead of using setInterval, you can use setTimeout to display the next slide. Every time you call setTimeout, you pick the time interval for setTimeout from the timings array so it is variable for each slide.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj thank you for your thought but it seem we must declare the time into array manually. the thing that I want is it can automatically define the time of the current slide running before move to the next slide

Answer (score 1):

You should use requstAnimationFrame for everything related to ui. This will make a smoother user experience and also prevent display updates if the web page is not visible (not active tab etc)

Thus works the same way as setTimeout.